# how to rotate a widget around one point?

Tags: flutter

I have an arrow widget. I would like to lock the arrow at the bottom point and rotate the arrow around it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sudyq.png)

```dart
widgetForInnerWidget: Center(
  child: Transform.rotate(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
    angle: 0,
    // максимальное значение 2.4 минимальное значение -1.6
    child: Transform.scale(
      scale: 2.3,
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/images/arrow.svg',
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
          Theme.of(context).color.special,
          BlendMode.srcIn,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.skewX(0.3),
    child:MyImage())
```

and play around the value to get what you want